# Unable to call function within class of extension

Tags: magento-1.8, class

I currently have some code on a product view page like:

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();  
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Module_Name')):  
$exclImg = $_product->getMediaGalleryExcludedImages();   
endif; ?>
```

The function `getMediaGalleryExcludedImages()` is contained within a file
`Module_Name/Model/Catalog/Product.php`

and looks like:

```
class Module_Name_Model_Catalog_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product {  

    public function getMediaGalleryExcludedImages() {

    // the function 

    }  
}
```

My problem is, that although the module is enabled and shows as such, the line:

```
$exclImg = $_product->getMediaGalleryExcludedImages();
```

isn't throwing an error on getting a value.

How is it that I am calling the function wrongly or what should I be registering?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento leverages what's called "[Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)" inside of PHP.  Whenever a method inside a class is called and does not exist, PHP will try to recover it by calling the method `__call()`.  This allows for more flexibility, graceful degradation, and dynamic getters and setters.

The method `__call()` exists inside of the class `Varien_Object`.  This is the base class that is extended by Blocks and Models. This means that all model and block classes that extend either `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` or `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` have access to these magic methods.

Let's take a look at `__call()` inside of `Varien_Object`:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
            case 'get' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return $data;

            case 'set' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return $result;

            case 'uns' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                $result = $this->unsetData($key);
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return $result;

            case 'has' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return isset($this->_data[$key]);
        }
        throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
    }
```

Magento setup the `__call()` to be a getter and setter for values inside of these classes.  When `__call()` evaluates a method, it checks for methods that begin with either 'get', 'set', 'has', or 'uns' (for unset).  This will then perform the appropriate actions against the `$_data` array property on the class.

As you can see, whenever you call any method from your class, if it begins with 'get', 'set', 'uns', or 'has', it will be caught by the `__call()` method and be returned as a getter or setter.  This is what you're experiencing with your method `getMediaGalleryExcludedImages()`.  It is returning `$this->_data['media_gallery_excluded_images']`.  If this value isn't set, it returns an empty string, but will not fail.

My guess is that your class is not being rewritten properly and is using the default model.  It will then be caught by the magic method.

Try looking into your rewrite configuration and see if there are any issues.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That was really useful to understand not just this, but concepts in general. I found that there was another class that was extending Mage_Catalog_Model_Product . I disabled that extension and now everything working.
Was there another plan of attack that i should have been looking at?

Comment: Actually that was the next part :)  Make sure you have no other rewrite conflicts.  You were a step ahead.  Great work!